# Show that $\sum_{k=4}^\infty \frac{9}{(k-1)^2} - \frac{9}{(k+2)^2} = \frac{769}{400}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, telescopic-series

I'm trying to compute this series.

$$S=\sum_{k=4}^\infty \dfrac{9}{(k-1)^2} - \dfrac{9}{(k+2)^2}$$

I have found the answer using a "shortcut" aka the Basel sum...
$$S=\sum_{k=4}^\infty \dfrac{9}{(k-1)^2} - \dfrac{9}{(k+2)^2} = \sum_{k=4}^\infty \dfrac{9}{(k-1)^2} - \sum_{k=4}^\infty \dfrac{9}{(k+2)^2}$$

Let $k-1=m$ and $k+2=n$, then

$$S=\sum_{m=3}^\infty \dfrac{9}{m^2} - \sum_{n=6}^\infty \dfrac{9}{n^2} = 9\left[\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}-\dfrac{5}{4}\right) - \left(\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}-\dfrac{5269}{3600}\right)\right]= \dfrac{769}{400}$$

This appears to be a telescoping series, so I'm looking for an algebraic approach. 
Wolfram Alpha computed the partial sum as

$$S_n =\dfrac{769 n^6 + 4614 n^5 - 803 n^4 - 33972 n^3 - 61724 n^2 - 43200 n - 14400}{400 n^2 (n + 1)^2 (n + 2)^2}$$

Can someone provide the details or outline the steps to arrive at $S_n$?

Comment: This is a telescoping sum. If you have a sum of the form $\sum a_{n+k} - a_n$, then if you let $b_n = a_n + a_{n+1} + \ldots + a_{n+k-1}$, then $a_{n+k} - a_n = b_{n+1} - b_n$. After all that, all the usual telescoping sum analysis works as usual: the partial sum will come to $\sum_{n=1}^N a_{n+k} - a_n = b_1 - b_{N+1}$, and the infinite sum is $b_1$ (assuming $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$).

Comment: How exactly did you "use the Basel sum" here?

Comment: The same method you _seem_ to have used to find $S$ can be used to find the partial sum $S_n$.  The only difference is you have to actually start with the definition of $S_n$.

Comment: @user170231 I would guess, in the sense that the Basel sum converges to something finite, hence splitting the infinite sum over the two expressions is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{m=3}^n\dfrac9{m^2}-\sum_{m=3}^n\dfrac9{(m+3)^2}$$

$$=9\left(\dfrac19+\dfrac1{16}+\dfrac1{25}-\dfrac1{(n+1)^2}-\dfrac1{(n+2)^2}-\dfrac1{(n+3)^2}\right)$$